# Can I query WHERE IN with multiple fields without using extra and raw sql?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-orm

I am using postgresql backend in my Django application. I am building a queryset for model manager, where I have a filter with multiple Q objects. I've got a list of tuples and I want one of Q objects to be something like this:

```
WHERE (id, id2) IN (VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1) ...);
```

where values are my list of tuples. Django FIELD__in lookup seems to be for one field only. Is there a way do this in one database query, preferably without using raw sql.

Edit: Using Django 1.9, PostgreSQL 9.4

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `reduce` on `operator.or_` on a `Q` object holding both ids that takes values from your list of tuples.

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

from django.db.models import Q

q = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(id=i, id2=j) for i, j in [(1, 1), (2, 1),...]))
```

All the tuples in the list are passed successively to the `Q` object and joined by `reduce` using a `or`.

You literally have:

```
q = Q(id=1, id2=1) | Q(id=2, id2=1) | Q(...)
```